# Can more than one App.xaml file exist in the Project consist of more than one SubProjects in Windows(8)

Tags: c#, windows-8

I am working on a Windows 8 app which is a collection of many Apps.Now what I want is I want to RUN the small Apps inside of the Main App.My main App will be available on Store but the Sub-Apps will not be available.They will be available only inside My main APP.

Now my question is-
How can I Run the Sub-App on the click of the button which is a part of my MAIN APP.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms771352(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @steveg89 he is talking about metro-style application not wpf.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that you can launch a second application from the first directly.  However, what you can do is launch a file, which will cause the default app for the file to launch.

```
bool success = await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchFileAsync(file, options);
```

Having said that, you have stated that the "sub apps" will not be available in the store.  Is what you actually want here simply to encapsulate different aspects of your functionality within separate screens?  You can expose this to the user through [in-app purchases](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Licensing-API-Sample-19712f1a) if that's your intent.

Another possibility would be to look at a background task if you are trying to relegate some heavy processing or something to a separate app.

Comment: To be more Precise- I just want to RUN my sub-app Xap file through Main App Xap file